# Concurrent Mark Sweep (CMS) GC occurs when Minor Collection runs

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, java, jvm-hotspot

We are using Java 1.6 Hotspot JVM. CMS GC should run when the Old Gen is nearing capacity. Minor Collection runs when Young Gen is nearing capacity.

However, on one server we are getting a CMS GC everytime a Minor Collection occurs. On the second server, this does not happen (normal operation). The jvm options are exactly the same on both servers; this happened after we upgraded to 64 bit webserver and JRE. JVM options are below:

```
<jvm-options>-Xms4096M -Xmx4096M</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-server</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Xss256k</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:NewSize=392M</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:MaxNewSize=392M</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:+DisableExplicitGC</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:+UseParNewGC</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:+PrintClassHistogram</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:+PrintGCDetails</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:PermSize=80m</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:MaxPermSize=80m</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-d64</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:CMSIncrementalSafetyFactor=75</jvm-options>
```

The CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction is not set, hence it is default value. What could be causing this? Can the two JVMs have different default values for non-defined JVM parameters?

Please take a look at the GC log below. The first line is the Minor Collection. A fraction of a second later, the CMS GC runs when it is only 10% full.

```
2013-02-28T13:49:55.446-0500: 1052247.742: [GC 1052247.742: [ParNew: 334791K->12629K(361280K), 0.0402234 secs] 687147K->366075K(4154176K) icms_dc=100 , 0.0409779 secs] [Times: user=0.28 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
2013-02-28T13:49:55.505-0500: 1052247.801: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 353445K(3792896K)] 366282K(4154176K), 0.0581835 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.01, real=0.06 secs]
2013-02-28T13:49:55.565-0500: 1052247.860: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2013-02-28T13:49:56.713-0500: 1052249.009: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.796/1.148 secs] [Times: user=6.03 sys=0.04, real=1.15 secs]
2013-02-28T13:49:56.713-0500: 1052249.009: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2013-02-28T13:49:56.808-0500: 1052249.104: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.094/0.095 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.00, real=0.10 secs]
2013-02-28T13:49:56.808-0500: 1052249.104: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start] 
  CMS: abort preclean due to time 2013-02-28T13:50:01.892-0500: 1052254.188: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 5.080/5.083 secs] [Times: user=5.98 sys=0.11, real=5.08 secs]
2013-02-28T13:50:01.911-0500: 1052254.207: [GC[YG occupancy: 56184 K (361280 K)]1052254.207: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0413292 secs]1052254.249: [weak refs processing, 0.0001292 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 353445K(3792896K)] 409629K(4154176K), 0.0421145 secs] [Times: user=0.63 sys=0.02, real=0.04 secs]
2013-02-28T13:50:01.954-0500: 1052254.250: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2013-02-28T13:50:04.032-0500: 1052256.328: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 2.078/2.078 secs] [Times: user=2.40 sys=0.03, real=2.08 secs]
2013-02-28T13:50:04.032-0500: 1052256.328: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2013-02-28T13:50:04.050-0500: 1052256.346: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.018/0.018 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
2013-02-28T13:50:44.487-0500: 1052296.783: [GC 1052296.783: [ParNew: 333781K->12385K(361280K), 0.0377823 secs] 686314K->366061K(4154176K) icms_dc=100 , 0.0385722 secs] [Times: user=0.29 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
2013-02-28T13:50:44.544-0500: 1052296.840: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 353676K(3792896K)] 366257K(4154176K), 0.0562739 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs]
2013-02-28T13:50:44.601-0500: 1052296.897: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2013-02-28T13:50:45.420-0500: 1052297.716: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.784/0.819 secs] [Times: user=5.79 sys=0.02, real=0.82 secs]
2013-02-28T13:50:45.420-0500: 1052297.716: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2013-02-28T13:50:45.517-0500: 1052297.813: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.096/0.097 secs] [Times: user=0.12 sys=0.00, real=0.10 secs]
2013-02-28T13:50:45.518-0500: 1052297.813: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
  CMS: abort preclean due to time 2013-02-28T13:50:50.524-0500: 1052302.820: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 4.903/5.006 secs] [Times: user=5.39 sys=0.05, real=5.01 secs]
2013-02-28T13:50:50.543-0500: 1052302.839: [GC[YG occupancy: 49968 K (361280 K)]1052302.839: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0695454 secs]1052302.909: [weak refs processing, 0.0001064 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 353676K(3792896K)] 403644K(4154176K), 0.0702712 secs]
```

Comment: I think since the addressing capacity has increased in 64 bit compared to that of 32 , default heap size in 64 bit is more . So JVM might have had heuristics about Heap size and depending on heap size the type of GC algorithms changes... In general Old generation size is more so CMS is appropriate . Now in 64 bit webserver even younger generation size is also more (proportionately from heap) so JVM heuristics made CMS GC to run .. (this answer is pure guess )

Comment: You have GC log enabled. If you attach GC log snippets from both server it would help to identify issue. Concerning 32 to 64 switch, objects are large in 64bit JVM, so heap pressure should increase.

Comment: good call Alexey; I've added the GC log

Answer (score 1):

From your logs it seems that CMS is running continuously.
Normally CMS will delay initial-mark for next young GC (because young space have smallest size right after young GC). This is a reason why you are seeing CMS initial-mark right after ParNew.

icms_dc=100 suggest that CMS were running non-stop even before ParNew.

I have seen this once [(read more details)](http://blog.ragozin.info/2012/06/story-of-relentless-cms.html), in my case CMS were triggered by premanent space reaching occupancy threshold. Check your permspace occupation, there is a chance that you should increase it.

You could also configure different occupancy threshold for permanent space (though I'm not sure how it will work with iCMS).

```
-XX:CMSInitiatingPermOccupancyFraction=N
```

Comment: My permgen is at 90.5% of max committed. This is the same across two identical servers (hardware, software and configuration), though only one displays this behavior.

Comment: My next step is to remove iCMS (since we have 8 cores on the server, there is no need for this; simply existed there before) and explicitly define CMSInitiatingPermOccupancyFraction=85.  My rep is too low, but vote up for this answer and your blog.

Comment: going into production soon, will have an update; we will mirror our settings on the other servers which reflect above suggestions and have been working fine for the last week, =)

Comment: no longer constantly CMS GCing, looks good, thanks Alexey; though we have a new issue. The application ran one CMS GC per day and operated very smoothly. After the third day, the application froze up. It seems did not recover from the CMS. Upon further inspection, correlating the GC logs and access logs, the issue is with the Minor Collector (UseParNewGC). The minor collector does not run after the CMS. Wierd, because it worked the first few times. Using Hotspot 1.6.37 64 bit.

Comment: Alexey, confirmed promotion failure occurring due to old gen fragmentation. As per your blog [link](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/10/cms-heap-fragmentation-follow-up-1.html), added the -XX:PrintFLSStatistics=1 option and can see the max chunk size shrinking.

Comment: Alexey, confirmed promotion failure occurring due to old gen fragmentation. As per your [blog](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/10/cms-heap-fragmentation-follow-up-1.html), added the -XX:PrintFLSStatistics=1 option and can see the max chunk size shrinking. To address the fragmentation, I will increase the new gen size to allow small objects to die in new gen before getting promoted. The promotion failures are due to many small objects (24 objects all under 500b). Also will reduce my oldPLABsize to 16. stay tuned

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html).

Firstly you have to define a consistent configuration (so in particular choose CMS every time...)
A long time ago, I performed many performance tests and I tried to use this option '-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction'. I had observed a behavior that is different of what is explained in the documentation (it's often the case with GC tuning...)

After some research I discovered a not documented option named '-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly'. This option should have disappeared since Java 6, but it was a convenient workaround to operate CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction.

I don't try with Java 7 nor Java 8. So this tip is probably obsolet. Maybe not ^^